# Keep having to reset BIOS for computer to function

Tags: bios, cmos, blank-screen

I have a year old computer that keeps just showing a black screen. As in there is nothing being sent to the monitor. Upon taking out the CMOS battery to reset the bios it works again however it only lasts a day or so before the same black screen issue reoccurs.

We have gotten a new CMOS battery and tried using that as well to see if the battery is dead however it did not fix anything. At this point I am wondering what may be wrong?

Comment: Have you reflashed the BIOS? It may be corrupt.

Comment: @CharlieRB Wouldn't resetting the BIOS do that?

Comment: No. What you are doing is resetting the existing BIOS to its defaults. Flashing BIOS writes the code into the chipset. Go to the manufacturer's website to get the latest BIOS update and follow the instructions to update it.

Comment: @CharlieRB How do I flash the one from the manufactory's site?

Comment: Follow their instructions how to do it.

Comment: @CharlieRB Okay and when I'm searching for these, am I searching for the motherboard manufactory or BIOS maker?

Comment: If it is a name brand computer, like Dell, IBM, HP, etc., you can go to that manufacturer's site. If it's a custom build, you will go to the motherboard manufacturer's site.

Comment: @CharlieRB flashed it. Still not working.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Sounds like a defective motherboard. You should contact the manufacturer for support.